# exclude hidden columnname and corresponding colmodel from exporting to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Guys I need some help here. I have hidden colModel in jqgird when I export my grid in excel I am getting all the data including hidden ones. So my requirement is not to display any hidden column name and corresponding colmodel while doing export. The colModel firstValue and secondVlaue have property hidden= true and I need It(columnname and cell value) to not appear in excel if its hidden. can you please provide me some guidance/suggestion as how this can be achieved.  It's been 3 days and I can't figure out how this can be achieved. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
grid = jQuery("#list2");
                grid.jqGrid({
                    datastr : comparePatchData,
                    datatype: 'jsonstring',
                    colNames:['Name',starheader, header1, header2],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:'elementName',index:'elementName', width:90},
                        {name:'isPrasentinXml1',index:'isPrasentinXml1', width:100, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent},
                        {name:'isPrasentinXml2',index:'isPrasentinXml2', width:100, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent},
                        {name:'isPrasentinXml3',index:'isPrasentinXml3', width:100, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent}
                    ],
                    pager : '#gridpager2',
                    rowNum:12,
                    scrollOffset:0,
                    height: 320,
                    autowidth:true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    loadonce:true,
                    jsonReader: {
                        repeatitems: false,
                        page: function() { return 1; },
                        root: "response"
                    },
                    subGrid: true,
                    // define the icons in subgrid
                    subGridOptions: {
                        "plusicon"  : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                        "minusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                        "openicon"  : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                        //expand all rows on load
                        "expandOnLoad" : false
                    },

                    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
                        //console.info(subgrid_id+", "+row_id);
                        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id, iData = -1;
                        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                        //pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
                        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' style='overflow-y:auto' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");

                        $.each(comparePatchData.response,function(i,item){
                            if(item.id === row_id) {
                                iData = i;
                                return false;
                            }

                        });
                        if (iData == -1) {
                            return; // no data for the subgrid
                        }

                        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                            datastr : comparePatchData.response[iData],
                            datatype: 'jsonstring',
                            colNames: ['Name','Value1','Value2','Value3'],
                            colModel: [
                                {name:"name",index:"name",width:90},
                                {name:"firstValue",index:"firstValue",width:100, hidden:true},
                                {name:"secondValue",index:"secondValue",width:100, hidden:true},
                                {name:"thirdValue",index:"thirdValue",width:100}
                            ],
                            rowNum:10,
                            //pager: pager_id,
                            sortname: 'name',
                            sortorder: "asc",
                            height: 'auto',
                            autowidth:true,
                            jsonReader: {
                                repeatitems: false,
                                //page: function() { return 1; },
                                root: "attribute"
                            }
                        });

                        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
                    }
                });
                grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager2',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
                grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#gridpager2',{
                    caption:"Export to Excel", 
                    onClickButton : function () { 
                        jQuery("#list2").excelExport();
                    } 
                });
                
                
                
//response

{
"response": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "elementName": "libgtop2-devel-2.14.4-3.el5",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": false,
        "isPrasentinXml2": false,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "thirdValue": "libgtop2-devel-2.14.4-3.el5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "elementName": "ifd-egate-0.05-15",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": false,
        "isPrasentinXml2": false,
        "isPrasentinXml3": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "thirdValue": "ifd-egate-0.05-15"
            }
        ]
    }
```

```css
var response = JSON.parse(responseJSON).response;
var csv = arrayToCSV(response);

function arrayToCSV(arr) {
    var columnNames = [];
    var rows = [];
    for (var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++) {
        // Each obj represents a row in the table
        var obj = arr[i];
        // row will collect data from obj
        var row = [];
        for (var key in obj) {
            // Don't iterate through prototype stuff
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
            // Collect the column names only once
            if (i === 0) columnNames.push(prepareValueForCSV(key));
            // Collect the data
            row.push(prepareValueForCSV(obj[key]));
        }
        // Push each row to the main collection as csv string
        rows.push(row.join(','));
    }
    // Put the columnNames at the beginning of all the rows
    rows.unshift(columnNames.join(','));
    // Return the csv string
    return rows.join('\n');
}

// This function allows us to have commas, line breaks, and double 
// quotes in our value without breaking CSV format.
function prepareValueForCSV(val) {
    val = '' + val;
    // Escape quotes to avoid ending the value prematurely.
    val = val.replace(/"/g, '""');
    return '"' + val + '"';
}
```

```html
<div id="test" >
  <table id="list2"></table>
 </div>
  {
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @Tony Tomov 4.6